# Condition in ruby on rails - if else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not really sure what this means. This is from Ruby on Rails in controller class and been trying to figure out what the below code do.

```
payload = if params.key? :data
            //do something
          else 
            //else do something
          end
```

This is in the controller class. What does the `params.key? :data` do?

The `data` variable doesn't exist in the whole class but just in this block.

Comment: there's no variable `data` in this snippet.

Comment: "What does the params.key? :data do" - it calls method `key?` on object `params` and passes a symbol `:data` as an argument.

Comment: Might be easier to recognize with parentheses: `params.key?(:data)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:data` is not a variable but a symbol.

`.key?` is a method and in ruby you do not need parentheses to pass a parameter such as `:data`.

So this bit of code asks if `params` has the symbol `:data` as a key (in a map) and uses the returning boolean for the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet `data` is not a variable, it is a [symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Symbol.html) literal. Java doesn't have a direct counterpart of Ruby's symbols AFAIR, but you can think of it as of some immutable identifier (kinda "immutable string with some additional cool properties that don't matter in the context we discuss here").

Next, `params` represents query params and is provided by the underlying middleware. It is a Hash-like data structure where `Hash` is a Ruby's counterpart of Java's `HashMap` that maps keys to values.

Next, `params.key? :data` is the same as `params.key?(:data)` - parentheses around method's arguments are optional in Ruby in most cases, and people tend to abuse this controversial feature. It just checks if `params` hash(map) contains a `:data` key (see [Hash#key?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F)).

And finally since everything in Ruby is an expression, `if... else... end` has a meaningful return value (the result of the particular branch execution) that is further assigned to the `payload`.